# Select just fill columns in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table with too many columns ex,700 columns.
In every step of my work some of these columns will be fill from first column to another columns,for ex,from first column until 200th column.
I need to have just fill columns.
How to select that show just fill columns?
Thanks

Comment: A table with 700 columns is most probably wrongly designed

Comment: What defines whether or not a column is a "fill" column?

Comment: What do you mean by **just fill**? For instance, if you have two records, one with columns 1-200 with data while the other with columns 1-250, what do you expect to received from the select?

Answer (score 0):

700 columns is bad design.

**Best solution**: review your data base design.

**Simple solution** : split the table into several tables each handling *similar data* and having a 1-1 relationship to the "main" table

### Say you have this

**MainTable**

```
 ID
 field1
 field2
 field3
 ...
 field10
 field11
 ...
 field700
```

### You should end with this :

**Maintable**

```
 field1
 field2
 field3
 ...
 field99
```

**Subtable1**

```
 ID
 field100
 ...
 field199
```

**Subtable2**

```
 ID
 field200
 ...
 field299
```

and so on

and then you should make queries like this, with only the tables containing the relevant data :

```
SELECT *
FROM mainttable T
INNER JOIN subtable1 T1 on  T.ID=T1.ID
INNER JOIN subtable2 T2 on  T.ID=T2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks,I will do it.